# How to add a view values to PDO fetchAll result

Tags: php

I would like to add a few entries to the result of a

```
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, I cannot get what I add to be additional key/value pairs in the same array index.

A dump of the $rows gives this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "Gary"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(6) "Cotton"
    ["job_title"]=>
    string(11) "Web Manager"
    ["telephoneNumber"]=>
    string(12) "123-456-7890"
    ["email"]=>
    string(22) "first.last@org.ca"
    ["street"]=>
    string(19) "street"
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "city"
    ["prov"]=>
    string(2) "ON"
    ["postal"]=>
    string(7) "K1A 0X1"
  }
}
```

I would like to add

```
$response = array('max_upo' => "false", 'num_contacts' => "1", 'org_acronym' => "TEST");
```

such that the dump looks like

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "Gary"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(6) "Cotton"
    ["job_title"]=>
    string(11) "Web Manager"
    ["telephoneNumber"]=>
    string(12) "123-456-7890"
    ["email"]=>
    string(22) "first.last@org.ca"
    ["street"]=>
    string(19) "street"
    ["city"]=>
    string(6) "city"
    ["prov"]=>
    string(2) "ON"
    ["postal"]=>
    string(7) "K1A 0X1"
    ["max_upo"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["num_contacts"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["org_acronym"]=>
    string(4) "TEST"
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
$rows[0][] = $response;
$rows = array_merge($response, $rows);
```

and variations to no avail.  The response array gets added,, but in a new index.

Comment: Try `$result[0] = array_merge($rows[0], $response);` This would work if you are fetching only one line from the database. Otherwise you'll have to do it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach is:

```
foreach ($response as $k=>$v) {
    $rows[0][$k] = $v;
}
print_r($rows[0]);
```

Comment: I get this added to the $rows array: `[0]=>'
   string(5) "false"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    string(4) "true"`

Comment: Sorry, I took it the wrong way. I just edited the code, please try again!